# box-shadow on android browser

Tags: android, html, css

hi i have a weird problem on a project
im trying to create a page for tablets and android browsers 
i have a html dock like this :

```
<div id="background">
<img alt="home" src="http://192.168.2.1/image/new_icons/tv.png" id="tv">
<img alt="contact" src="http://192.168.2.1/image/new_icons/movie.png" id="movie">
</div>
```

css :

```
#background {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left:10%;
height: 70px;
background: url("../img/back-left.png") no-repeat;
width:1000px;
}

html body div#background img
{
width:72px;
height: 72px;
float: left;
margin: 3px;
top:-20px;
position: relative;
}

html body div#background  img:hover
{
top:-35px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 50px 10px #FFAC30;
}
```

i want to add box-shadow for img:hover
it works fine in pc browser and even chrome for android :

[image]

but this is how it loads on android browser :

[image]

where is the problem ?

Comment: What versions of Android are you testing for? Try adding the standard `box-shadow`. It is supported in Android 4+, http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

Comment: i did there is no diffrence,im usint version 4 and tested on many devices

Comment: You could try without the spread radius, the fourth pixel value, likethis: `1px 1px 50px #FFAC30`. It might not be supported. This will change the look slightly.

Comment: still the same... can this be a browser bug or something?

Comment: Are you using something to emulate hover on Android?

Comment: its not just about hover i add a class to an image abd try to add box-shadow same thing happens

Comment: Found this site that tests box-shadow for different devices. Does it work there? http://thany.nl/apps/BoxShadows/